# Return a list of data made from an Ajax/HTTP in the order they were called

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ajax, http, callback

Is there a way to display your AJAX data back in the order in which you called your AJAX requests, without using promises, also no synchronous code or jQuery, but simply pure javascript?

For example:

```
//file 1 takes 3 seconds & file2 takes 1 second
input:  ['example1.com', 'example2.com']
output: [example1_response, example2_response]
```

I started by setting up a small toy problem in my HTML page. I append two placeholder `<div>`'s with the text `wait` inside my webpage & then as my url requests completed the appropriate `<div>`'s placeholder text was replaced. But still it doesn't achieve the end goal of loading my content based on the order in which I made my requests.

JSFIDDLE:https://jsfiddle.net/nf4p1bgf/5/

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
var urls = [ "website1.com", "website2.com"];


//Helper function to simulate AJAX request
function fakeAjax(url,cb) {
  var fake_responses = {
    "website1.com": "data from website1.com",
    "website2.com": "data from website2.com"
  };

  var randomDelay = (Math.round(Math.random() * 1E4) % 8000) + 1000;
  console.log(`Requesting: ${url}. Response time: ${randomDelay}`);

  setTimeout(function(){
    cb(fake_responses[url]);
  },randomDelay);
}


urls.forEach(function(url) {
  //creating placeholder <div>'s before AJAX data  returns
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.innerHTML = "this is a place holder - please wait";
  body.appendChild(div);

  fakeAjax(url, function(data) {
    div.innerHTML = data;
  });
});
```

**EDIT & SOLUTION** JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/fa707qjc/11/

```
//*********** HELPERS (SEE CODE BELOW HELPERS SECTION) ***********/

var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
var urls = ["website1.com","website2.com"];

function fakeAjax(url,cb) {
  var fake_responses = {
    "website1.com": "data from website1.com",
    "website2.com": "data from website2.com"
  };
  var randomDelay = (Math.round(Math.random() * 1E4) % 8000) + 1000;
  console.log(`Requesting: ${url}. Response time: ${randomDelay}`);

  setTimeout(function(){
    cb(fake_responses[url]);
  },randomDelay);
}

function createElement(typeOfElement, text){
  var element = document.createElement(typeOfElement)
  element.innerHTML = text;
  return element;
}


function handleResponse(url, contents){
  //if I haven't recieved response from x url
  if( !(url in responses)){
    responses[url] = contents;
  }

  //defining order for response outputs
  var myWebsites = ['website1.com','website2.com'];

  // loop through responses in order for rendering
  for(var url of myWebsites){
    if(url in responses){
        if(typeof responses[url] === "string"){
            console.log( responses[url])
            //mark already rendered
            var originalText = responses[url];
            responses[url] = true;
            var p = createElement('p', originalText);
            body.appendChild(p);
        }
    } 
    //can't render it / not complete
    else{
        return;
    }
  }
}



//*********** CODE START ***********
function getWebsiteData(url) {
    fakeAjax(url, function(text){
        console.log(`Returning data from ${url} w/response: ${text}`)
        handleResponse(url, text);
    });
}

//As we get our responses from server store them
var responses = {};

// request all files at once in "parallel"
urls.forEach(function(url){
  getWebsiteData(url);
})
```

Comment: 1. I don't think what you want to achieve is possible; 2. This question belongs on StackOverflow.

Comment: This is a specific feature request, not a request for a general code review. Have you tried callbacks?

Comment: @Kapol - Foruntately I found a solution thanks to Kyle Simpsons work on Github - https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

```
Promise.all(urls.map(function(url) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    request(url, function(data, error) {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }
      resolve(data);
    })
  });
})).then(function(results) {
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks - that works too. I also found a solution with no promises above . Kyle Simpson's Async Javascript  for YDKJS really helped clarify my problem.

Comment: @CliffordFajardo IMHO, you shouldn't use anything esle but Promise. It's the least frustrating solution in the long run.

Comment: I agree. This was a question I got asked for a frontend interview at a top tech company in the valley & I wasn't allowed to use promises or any libraries